# Dealing with NSRect in python

Tags: python, macos, core-graphics

I have a function:

```
def getMediaBox(doc, pageNum):
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, pageNum)
    return CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)
```

which returns:

```
<NSRect origin=<NSPoint x=0.0 y=0.0> size=<NSSize width=499.0 height=709.0>>
```

Is this a data type that python can do anything with? What do the <> brackets mean? Ideally, I want to query and test the size numbers.

Interestingly, CoreGraphics seems to accept nested lists, like [[0,0],[499,709]] when it expects an NSRect.

Many thanks: your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that have to use instances, such as maxX of CGRect.
However, I've tried things like 
 x = mediaBox.maxX(self)
and I get:
NSRect' object has no attribute 'maxX'

Answer (score 0):

You can query the NSRect object with the following lines:

```
x = CGRectGetWidth(mediaBox)
y = CGRectGetHeight(mediaBox)
```